# Reducing over multiple joins in CouchDB

Tags: join, couchdb

In my CouchDB database, I have the following models (implemented as documents in the database with different `type` fields):

- Team: `name`, `id` (has many matches, has many fans)
- Match: `name`, `team_a`, `team_b`, `time` (has many teams, has many tweets)
- Fan: `team_id` (has many tweets)
- Tweet: `time`, `sentiment`, `fan_id`

I want to average the tweet sentiment for each team. If I were using SQL I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT avg(sentiment)
FROM team
    JOIN match on team.id = match.team_a OR team.id = match.team_b
    JOIN fan on fan.team = team.id
    JOIN tweet on (tweet.time BETWEEN match.time AND match.time + interval '1 hour') AND tweet.user = fan.id
GROUP BY team.id
```

However in CouchDB you can at best do 1 join in a view function, [as explained in the docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/ddocs/views/joins.html) (by emitting the join field as the key).

How can this be better modelled in CouchDB to allow for this query to work? I don't really want to denormalise too much, but I guess I will if I have to?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complex, but I use what I call "tertiary indexes". The goal is to be able to write a view that is applied to another view. Unfortunately, the only way to do this is to use a view to write data to a secondary database and then have another view that works on that database. Doing this requires an outside process - I use a script that listens to the _changes feed of the primary database, and then updates the relevant documents in the secondary database  when something changes.

So in your example your secondary database could consist of a single document for each team with all of the (or the latest) match/fan/tweet data in that one document. Then you write a view that extracts the sentiment (or whatever) from that secondary database.